# WSO2 SP Siddhi xml parsing from wso2event

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have input stream as wso2event on wso2 SP, and it contain timestamp and payload. Payload is in xml format. How can I parse this payload to variables? I see this doc https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-map-xml/api/4.0.11/ but i don't know, how get incoming wso2event to sourcemapper and then pars it to variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**siddhi-map-*** extensions are used to map input/output event attributes at the source/sink level.

Since this xml payload is an attribute of another stream, you can use **siddhi-execution-map** extension to create a map from that xml.

Then you can handle the xml payload as a hashmap within the siddhi app.

Please refer to the documentation[1] for more details on this.

[1] https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-execution-map/

Comment: Thnaks for reply. I used createFromXML function as you mentioned and I got map, with only one key. Key of first element in xml.

I have similiar xml as you can see bellow ->

<Envelope>
  <Body>
   <id>123</id>
  </Body>
</Envelope>

And after I get map from xml and then use get() function. But I have to use get(map, '{namespace}Envelope') to get some data, but if I use {namespace}Id or {namespace}Envelope{namespace}Body{namespace}Id I get **id xsi:nil="true"**. What can I do to get Id data?

Comment: I posted answer below, because there is bad implementation of createFromXml function. Please could you look at it and refer this bug to the wso2 community? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I realized, that there is bug in https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-execution-map/api/latest/ **createFromXML** function. This function correctly parse xml file over each element, but there is badly defined HashMap, because function is called recursively and every cycle is created new map and override data in old map. So at the end, there is map with only one key.

```
private Object getMapFromXML(OMElement parentElement) throws XMLStreamException {
    Map<Object, Object> topLevelMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    Iterator iterator = parentElement.getChildElements();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        OMElement streamAttributeElement = (OMElement) iterator.next();
        String key = streamAttributeElement.getQName().toString();
        Object value;
        if (streamAttributeElement.getFirstElement() != null) {
            value = getMapFromXML(streamAttributeElement);
        } else {
            logger.info("getFirstElement is null now, iam in else - " + key);
            String elementText = streamAttributeElement.getText();
            if (elementText.equals("true") || elementText.equals("false")) {
                value = Boolean.parseBoolean(elementText);
            } else {
                if (NumberUtils.isNumber(elementText)) {
                    try {
                        value = numberFormat.parse(elementText);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        value = elementText;
                    }
                } else {
                    value = elementText;
                }
            }
        }
        topLevelMap.put(key, value);
    }
    return topLevelMap;
}
```

topLevelMap should be declared as private global variable. Could someone make ticket on wso2 github to resolve this bug please?